# detach a class method and run it asynchronously in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have an API call that informs the caller that a task has started and internally executes the task asynchronously since the task might take enough time.

I tried to describe my scenario using two classes

- Manager class has the fire and forget method run_long_task, which now just contains a sleep call.
- MyAPI class exposes a method that wants to kick of the run_long_task but has to return immediately to the caller returning a "task id". In the meantime the manager::run_long_task started.

How can I achieve this functionality? How can I detach using a thread or std::async the run_long_task method? Currently the code is synchronous, therefore the modifyVarAndRunAsyncTask will block.

I would like to use something similar with this

std::thread({ run_async_task(); }).detach();

How can it be done using class members?

Code is below

```
 class Manager {
    public:
        void run_long_task(const uint32_t& ms) {
    
            try {
                //example job
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(ms));
            } catch( ... ) {
                cout << "report the error" << endl;
            }
    
        }
    
        Manager(int x, int y) : x_(x), y_(y) {}
    
        int getX() const {
            return x_;
        }
    
        int getY() const {
            return y_;
        }
    
    private:
        int x_;
        int y_;
    };
    
    class MyAPI {
    
    public:
        MyAPI(const shared_ptr<Manager> &manager, int var) : manager_(manager), var_(var) {}
    
        int getVar() const {
            return var_;
        }
    
        int modifyVarAndRunAsyncTask(int var, uint32_t ms) {
            var_ = var_ + var;
            manager_->run_log_task(50000);
            return var_;
        }
    
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<Manager> manager_ {nullptr};
        int var_ {0};
    };
    
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
        std::shared_ptr<Manager> manager = std::make_shared<Manager>(1,2);
        auto api = std::make_shared<MyAPI>(manager, 5);
        runs for ever (1) {
            api->modifyVarAndRunAsyncTask(10, 10000);
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: You are looking for "threads"

Comment: Yes, but I would like to learn how to do this for class members

Comment: See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread specifically `std::thread t5(&foo::bar, &f); // t5 runs foo::bar() on object f`

Comment: @RichardCritten this is what I am asking, how do I call Manager::run_long_task from modifyVarAndRunAsyncTask ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I call Manager::run_long_task from modifyVarAndRunAsyncTask?

```
//first argument has to be "this" for the member function
std::thread t1(&Manager::run_long_task, manager_.get(), 50000); 
t1.detach();
```

Although the constructor for `std::thread` takes a function and passes it's arguments, I think it is easier to just use a lambda:

```
std::thread t1(
    [this](){ manager_->run_long_task(50000); }
);
t1.detach();
```